# Peaks detection in delta lookback interval for real time algorithm

Tags: classification, peak-detection

So I am developing a signal processing algorithm to classify in real time depending on how many peaks I have in my time series, in a delta. I implemented a circular buffer and accumulator to keep in memory the number of peaks in that buffer. However, it seems like for some reason, my accumulator reduces drastically when the signal oscillates a lot. and I don't know why.

I plot here a picture of my algorithm working and look ad how the accumulator 8the red plot) changes in the plot.
[image]
The algorithm that I am developing (it's in a development stage) is the following:

```
def brakkel_peak_classification_v2(y: list, lag, threshold, influence, delta=None, absolute=True):
# Section creator
curr_interval_start = 0
signals = np.zeros(len(y))
filteredY = np.array(y)
avgFilter = [0] * len(y)
stdFilter = [0] * len(y)
avgFilter[lag - 1] = np.mean(y[:lag])
stdFilter[lag - 1] = np.std(y[:lag])
circular_buffer = []
accumulator = 0
on_event_a = False
on_event_b = False
intervals_a = []
intervals_b = []
accumulator_list = []
for i in range(lag, len(y)):
    if abs(y[i] - avgFilter[i - 1]) > threshold * stdFilter[i - 1]:  # peak
        if y[i] > avgFilter[i - 1]:
            signals[i] = 1
        else:
            signals[i] = 1 if absolute else -1
        if abs(signals[i]) == 1 and signals[i - 1] == 0:
            curr_interval_start = i

        filteredY[i] = influence * y[i] + (1 - influence) * filteredY[i - 1]
        avgFilter[i] = np.mean(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
        stdFilter[i] = np.std(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
    else:  # No peak
        signals[i] = 0
        filteredY[i] = y[i]
        avgFilter[i] = np.mean(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
        stdFilter[i] = np.std(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])

    # evaluate
    if i < lag+5000:
        # Fill the buffer
        circular_buffer.append(signals[i])
        if int(signals[i]) == 1:
            accumulator += 1
    else:
        if accumulator >=50:
            on_event_a = True
        elif 20 <= accumulator <=50:
            on_event_b = True
        else:
            if on_event_a:
                intervals_a.append([curr_interval_start, i])
                on_event_a=False
                on_event_b=False
            elif on_event_b and not on_event_a:
                intervals_b.append([curr_interval_start, i])
                on_event_a = False
                on_event_b = False

        # update accumulator
        if int(signals[i]) == 1:
            accumulator += 1

        last_value_circular_buffer = circular_buffer[0]
        if last_value_circular_buffer == 1:
            accumulator -= 1
        circular_buffer.pop(0)
        circular_buffer.append(signals[i])
    accumulator_list.append(accumulator)

intervals = {'A': intervals_a, 'B': intervals_b}
return dict(signals=np.asarray(signals),
            avgFilter=np.asarray(avgFilter),
            stdFilter=np.asarray(stdFilter),
            intervals=intervals)
```

Any help on how could I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: "my accumulator reduces drastically" Please, clarify what you mean: what is the role of the accumulator, and what exactly is being reduced.

Comment: The accumulator is a measure of how many peaks I have in my search back window. I compute, as you see in the code, how many peaks I have by adding a 1 if the current value of the signal is over the threshold and a 0 if it is under zero and reduce 1 if the popped element was a peak. So I expect that in a high excitation section of the input signal, I should have a big number of peaks reflected in the accumulator, but it looks like when we enter in that high excitation part, the threshold of my algorithm goes up a lot and does not detect any peak.